# How can I change the "Edit" tab name to something more meaningful?

Tags: 8

I would like to change the Edit tab from Edit to Edit Client.  The content type is Client.

I tried using the following code in the bartik.theme file in the web/core/themes directory (running drupal 8.5.4).

```
function bartik_preprocess_menu_local_task(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['element']['#link']['title']) && $variables['element']['#link']['title'] == 'Edit') {
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if ($node && $node->getType() == 'client') {
      $variables['link']['#title'] = t('Edit Client');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope you're just using Bartik here for testing purposes. You're not suppose to touch anything in /core folder. Because when you update Drupal, it will override everything inside the /core folder; thus, you will lose all your changes. If you like Bartik and want to use it as your theme, then you should create a new theme and use Bartik as your base theme.

Answer (score 2):

Use `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter` see the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.5.x). You can get a dynamic title combining tokens and the translation API.